# Is there a continuous bijection from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\tilde{\Bbb R^n}$?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $\tilde{\Bbb R^n}$ be $\Bbb R^n$ with a finer topology, does there exsist a continuous bijection
$$ f\colon \Bbb R^n \to \tilde{\Bbb R^n} \text{?}$$

Probably there is a simple argument against it that I am missing?

Comment: @Masacroso I always have problems with left and right, but I guess not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "finer" means "strictly finer", then such an $f$ doesn't exist.

Suppose $f\colon (\mathbb{R}^n,\tau_0) \to (\mathbb{R}^n,\tau_1)$ is a continuous bijection, where $\tau_0$ is the standard topology and $\tau_1 \supseteq \tau_0$. If we weaken the topology on the codomain to $\tau_0$, the map remains continuous, and thus, by the invariance of domain, $f \colon (\mathbb{R}^n,\tau_0) \to (\mathbb{R}^n,\tau_0)$ is a homeomorphism. Then $$\operatorname{id} = f\circ f^{-1} \colon (\mathbb{R}^n,\tau_0) \to (\mathbb{R}^n,\tau_1)$$ is a continuous bijection, which means $\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_0$.